# unset scrollToIndex after setting it

Tags: react-virtualized

I'm using an `InfiniteLoader` with a `Table` and I have the indices of some entries that match a specific criteria stored in state. If the user would want to go through those entries, I would have to pass down to the `Table` each index (following a button click) and use it in `scrollToIndex`. However, after it's passed down, I would have to make it `null` again, otherwise if the user were to scroll up/down the `Table`, he would always end to the same index specified by `scrollToIndex` instead of the current scroll position.

Is there a better way to do that, other than setting the state twice, once with an index and then with a `null` value?

Hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Table` (and `Grid` and `List`) also have public methods for setting a 1-time scroll index. For `Table` the method is [`scrollToRow`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Table.md#scrolltorow-index-number) and you just pass it the index you want to scroll to. Maybe that would be more to your liking?

**Edit**: In response to the follow-up question of how you get a reference to `Table` if you also need to pass it to `InfiniteLoader`:

```
<InfiniteLoader {...infiniteLoaderProps}>
  {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (
    <Table
      {...tableProps}
      onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
      ref={(ref) => {
        this._tableRef = ref     // Store for yourself
        registerChild(ref) // And pass on to InfiniteLoader
      }}
    >
      {/* Columns ... */}
    </Table>
  )}
</InfiniteLoader>
```

Comment: How can I get a reference to the `Table` in order to call `scrollToRow` if I have to pass it `InfiniteLoader`'s `registerChild` as a `ref`?

Comment: You can stack refs. I have updated my answer to illustrate this.